# softmax activation function with infinite support ?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, statistical-physics, probability-distributions

Hi,

How do we calculate the terms of a [softmax activation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_activation_function) with an infinite support ?

That is, finding the $\{p_i\}_i$ with [$p_i = {{e^{q_i}} \over {\sum_{j=1}^\infty e^{q_j}
}}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_activation_function) (how to estimate the infinite sum?)

Any proposition or idea is welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To estimate in terms of what and under what conditions?

Comment: I'd be happy to answer this question if you clarified what you were asking.  What do you know about the $q_i$?  How are they determined?  If you don't have any information about the $q_i$, there is no way to provide an estimate.

Comment: Forgive me.

Supposing that we have an infinite network $G_{\infty}$ with vertices $V=[1, \infty]$.

Herein, $q_i$ is the value of the node $i \in V$.

The $q_i$ are determined by a random walk that starts from a node.

Comment: And once again, I ask, how are the $q_i$ determined?  If you know they're produced by some stochastic process, there is some hope of being able to provide a value for their softmax.  But if you don't know that process, there's no hope.